How to made these multi holes with Nodes
I'm trying to make these holes using the bump node method. I only want to make the holes one side of my mesh.




can u pls do pack resources before uploading? thx.

File is packed, you can review it, thanks.

i updated my answer

although you didn't provide your bump map, you can achieve the same with a voronoi texture like this:

So i replaced all randomness by setting roughness and randomness to 0 in the voronoi texture, the used a colorramp to sharpen the hole and put that in the bump node. Make sure if you are using cycles, that your material in settings had "bump only or bump and displacement". Also this only works that nice if you do a new uv unwrapping with "smart uv project" because it wasn't unwrapped even.

update:
the problem is that you have a bump map with alpha. So you have black and alpha.
Try this:


Thanks for providing the Node set up.

you are welcome
